# How can I factorise $c^4+4c^3+5c^2+8c+6$?

Tags: factoring

How can I factorise $c^4+4c^3+5c^2+8c+6$?

Comment: A first factor can be found by noting that $(-1)^4 + 4 (-1)^3 + 5 (-1)^2 + 8(-1) + 6 = 0$. I found this by trial and error.

Comment: You can find the answer [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=c%5E4%2B4c%5E3%2B5c%5E2%2B8c%2B6).

Comment: You can use Wolfram alpha, or simply note, by substitution, that $c=-1$ is a root of  your equation. In fact, you can also note that $c=-3$ is a root of your solution. Divide your expression by $(x+1)(x+3)$, and I got the answer $x^2+2$, so  the answer is $(c+1)(c+3)(c^2+2)$.

Comment: Not sure if this problem was edited correctly.  Should there be a minus sign on the first term?

Comment: @Mike I tried factorizing $-c^4 + 4c^3+5c^2+8c+6$, and got awkward roots, and no clear factors. It's clear that the minus  sign was  a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When all polynomial coefficients are integers, any rational root (if it exists at all) $\frac p q$ of $a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} +\ldots + a_1x + a_0$ must satisfy: $$ p | a_0,\ q | a_n$$

In this particular case, we have $a_n = 1$, so $q = 1$, i.e., any rational root of $x^4 + 4x^3 +5x^2 +8x + 6$ must be integer that divides $6$, i.e. $\frac p q\in\{-6,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,6\}$. Since all coefficients of your polynomial are positive, $\frac p q$ can't be positive.

One can then quickly check that $-1$ and $-3$ are indeed roots. That means that $$x^4 + 4x^3 +5x^2 +8x + 6 = (x+1)(x+3)r(x)$$ and if you use [long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division), you can find that $r(x) = x^2 +2$, which cannot be factored further over $\Bbb R$ (but can over $\Bbb C$, $x^2 + 2 = (x - i\sqrt 2)(x + i\sqrt 2)$).

---

Alternatively, you can note that $$x^4 + 4x^3 + 5x^2 +8x + 6 = (x^4 + 4x^3 + 3x^2) + (2x^2 +8x + 6) =\\ =x^2(x^2 + 4x + 3) + 2(x^2 + 4x + 3)  = (x^2 + 2)(x^2 + 4x + 3)$$

and find the roots by [qudratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula). Though, this is often harder to do in practice then the above method.

Answer (score 3):

If $c \geq 0$, then the polynomial is positive.

Hence the root should be complex or negative.

Try the factors of $6$, you can find that $-1$ and $-3$ are indeed the roots.

Hence some of the factors are $(x+1)$ and $(x+3)$, divide these terms and obtain the remaining quadratic terms.

Answer (score 2):

$$c^4+4c^3+5c^2+8c+6$$
$$c^4+4c^3+6c^2+4c+1-6c^2-4c-1+5c^2+8c+6$$
$$(c+1)^4-c^2+4c+5$$
$$(c+1)^4-(c+1)(c-5)$$
$$(c+1)((c+1)^3-c+5))$$
$$(c+1)(c^3+3c^2+2c+6)$$
$$(c+1)(c^2(c+3)+2(c+3))$$
$$(c+1)(c^2+2)(c+3)$$

Comment: These are not irreducible factors.

Comment: @Ennar I have added more details, thanks